# PHP MySQL update and strange characters?

Tags: php, mysql, json, curl

I have a form updating a table in mySQL. It seems to be working however when there are spaces in the forms input field it inserts a strange character. " Â  "

I have a feeling this has something to do with the character set I'm using but I'm not sure since I've never had this type of issue before.

Here is the code.

```
if($_POST){

    $db = new DB_Connection();
    $return = array();
    $sqlmap = array();
    $count = count($_POST['id']);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        foreach($_POST as $column => $value){
            if(empty($value)) $value = "";
            $sqlmap[$column] = $value[$i];
        }
        //echo "<pre>".print_r($sqlmap,true)."</pre>";
        unset($sqlmap['command']);

        $tableid = $sqlmap['id'];
        $exclude = array("id","Date");

        $sql = "UPDATE contact_form SET ";
        $sqlloop = "";
        foreach($sqlmap as $key => $value){
                if(!in_array($key,$exclude)){
                    $sqlloop .= "`".$key."`='".mysql_real_escape_string($value)."',";
                }
        }
        $sqlloop .= " Date = CURDATE() ";
        $sqlloop = str_replace("Â","",$sqlloop);
        $sqlloop = str_replace("Â ","",$sqlloop);
        $sqlloop = str_replace("_"," ",$sqlloop);
        //$sqlloop = substr($sqlloop, 0, -1);
        $sql .= $sqlloop;
        $sql .= " WHERE id = '".$tableid."';";
        //echo $sql;
        $result = $db->query($sql,"website");
        if (!$result) $return['error'] = "ERROR:".$db->getError();
        else {
            $return['success'] = "SUCCESS";
            echo json_encode($return);
        }
    }
}
```

It only seems to happen when there is "blank" space. I've tried stripping and repalceing and a few other things but nothing seems to be working.

Help?

UPDATE:

So I've been doing some digging on Google and I found that when I serialize the form this blanks entries are getting encoded as %c2%A0. I am using the Jquery . serialize(). Is this normal behavior for empty input serialization?

Below is my Jquery code:

```
  $("form[name='selectedform']").submit(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "/system/curlbridge.php",
            data: $("#selectedform").serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                    alert(data.Sucess);

            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                alert("Status: " + textStatus); 
                alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
            } 
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

`%C2%A0` is the UTF-8 encoding of codepoint U+00A0, also known as the non-breaking space. It's not clear where this is being generated.

- http://unicodey.com/?hex=%25c2%25A0
- http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/A0/index.htm

The reason you're seeing `Â` is because your code is treating UTF-8 data as if it were Latin-1, although this may just be a display-time issue. To  make sure your browser interprets the data you're outputting as UTF-8, include the relevant header: http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset